# Accuracy in Caffe keeps on 0.1 and does not change

Tags: neural-network, caffe

Through all training process, accuracy is 0.1. What am I doing wrong?

Model, solver and part of log here:
https://gist.github.com/yutkin/3a147ebbb9b293697010

Topology in png format: 
[image]

P.S. I am using the latest version of Caffe and g2.2xlarge instance on AWS.

Comment: it is impossible to tell from the information you sent. How do you initialize the weights? random? finetuning pre-trained weights? It seems like your ReLUs are saturated: their output is in the "0" range and thus gradients are zero. Try replacing the ReLUs with PReLU. see if it changes things for you,

Comment: @Shai: take a look at the solver.prototxt file. It's not really impossible to tell!

Comment: Try adding `debug_info: true` to your `solver.prototxt` - this will make caffe print some information about activation and gradients during training. This information can be quite useful.

Comment: I don't think it is a good method to have a data dropout soon after reading image data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working on CIFAR-10 dataset which has 10 classes. When the training of a network commences, the first guess is usually random due to which your accuracy is `1/N`, where `N` is the number of classes. In your case it is `1/10`, i.e., `0.1`. If your accuracy stays the same over time it implies that your network isn't learning anything. This may happen due to a large learning rate. The basic idea of training a network is that you calculate the loss and propagate it back. The gradients are multiplied with the learning rate and added to the current weights and biases. If the learning rate is too big you may overshoot the local minima every time. If it is too small, the convergence will be slow. I see that your `base_lr` here is 0.01. As far as my experience goes, this is somewhat large. You may want to keep it at 0.001 in the beginning and then go on reducing it by a factor of 10 whenever you observe that the accuracy is not improving. But then anything below 0.00001 usually doesn't make much of a difference. The trick is to observe the progress of the training and make parameter changes as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

I know the thread is quite old but maybe my answer helps somebody. I experienced the same problem with an accuracy like a random guess.

What helped was to set the number of outputs of the last layer before the accuracy layer to the number of labels.

In your case that should be the `ip2` layer. Open the model definition of your net and set `num_outputs` to the number of labels.

See Section 4.4 for more information: [A Practical Introduction to Deep Learning with Caffe and Python](http://adilmoujahid.com/posts/2016/06/introduction-deep-learning-python-caffe/)